# Relation between spectrum and operator support

Tags: operator-theory

$f$ is a  function in  $C^{\infty}$ with compact support and $A$ is a self-adjoint operator. If $\mathrm{supp}(f)\cap\sigma(A)=\varnothing$, does this imply that $f(A)=0$?

Does anyone have an explanation why this is true ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the condition implies that $f|_{\sigma(A)}=0$. So you are doing functional calculus with the zero function. And $C^\infty$ plays no role here, the argument works for any continuous function.